# question related to for loop condition statement in C

Tags: c

I am trying to run a program in C, where the following statement is used in the code.

What does the following statement mean in the for loop condition of the given code?

I understand i is being initialised with value 3; and i gets updated in i = i-1 ; but what does the condition part mean? why only i; should it not be i>0? Why both statements give the same output , i.e *** .

**Code statements:**

```
int main()
{
    for(int i=3;i;i=i-1)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's the same as `i != 0`. Hmm, can't find a good duplicate, but it must be out there.

Comment: In C, a condition is considered true if it is non-zero, and false if it is zero. Therefore, the condition `i` is equivalent to `i != 0`.

Comment: It's a near universal computing convention that 0 is false and all other values are true. It applies to for(), while(), if() and ?: in C. There are number of reasons for this including early hardware having conditional machine instructions "jump equal to zero" and "jump not equal to zero" based on the contents of the relevant register.

Comment: @Persixty It's also consistent with boolean algebra, where multiplication corresponds to AND and addition corresponds to OR.

Comment: Beware taking advantage of this in situations where the loop body might mutate `i` to make it "skip" `0`, creating an infinite loop.

Comment: @Barmar Yes. It's ingrained in culture. The funny circle line symbol for standby on consumer electronics is actually a superposition on zero and 1. 0=OFF=FALSE and 1=ON=TRUE and by extension non-zero passes for true, The most natural form of loop is 'repeat until the difference I=N that being the difference is zero'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, `i` will be true when `!= 0`. Since your program must keep going until i is zero, It will keep checking. Here's a list of what the condition returns:

| i value | output returned by `i` |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | true |
| 2 | true |
| 1 | true |
| 0 | false (break) |

Answer (score 0):

C 2018 6.8.5.3 discusses the `for` statement, which has the form `for (clause-1; expression-2; expression-3) statement`, and paragraph 1 says:

> … The expression *expression-2* is the controlling expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body…

6.8.5 4 says:

> An iteration statement causes a statement called the *loop body* to be executed repeatedly until the controlling expression compares equal to 0.

Therefore, with `i` for the controlling expression, the loop body is executed repeatedly until `i` compares equal to zero.